# How best to "wire" BLSTM with some fixed inputs

Tags: recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I understand that for RNNs (of which BLSTM is one type) that the input vector is a representation of a variable in time. I have a classification problem that involves both a time-varying component which needs to be classified, and a vector of about 20 values that are static (for a given row - but vary, row to row). There is reason to believe that these 20 inputs will be useful in the classification, as there are differences in the input streams.

How would one wire this to BLSTM? Have a portion of the vector wired to the unrolled LSTM units, and the fixed portion wired to all of the unrolled LSTM units?

Comment: What's a BLSTM?

Comment: Bidirectional LSTM (Long Short-Term Memory)